# Multiline pattern matching whole line works in python but not in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find matches of the word TEST and replace it with MTEXT but for some reason it is not working. However it does work on Python.

The test File looks Like this

```
TEXT

TEXT


TEXT
```

I have used the MultiLine Option but still it is not working.

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Console.WriteLine($"{fileContents}");
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(fileContents, @"^(TEXT ?)$", options);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MATCH "+ m.Value);
}
```

I expect to find four matches but I get none.

Comment: found that replacing the literal whitespace after `Text` with `\s` yielded the expected results, i.e.:  `Matches(fileContents, @"^(TEXT\s?)$"`, though @Emma's suggestion is much more elegant (using word boundaries).

Comment: @Emma Yes! perfect! is there a reason why my pattern did not work on C# but it did work on python?

Comment: @FrankAlvaro Yours also works great as well!

Comment: You may need to use option Mutltiline or SingleLine.

Comment: In C#, you need to use `@"^(TEXT ?)\r?$"`

Comment: Do you really want to match `TEXT` in `TEXT and more words on this line`?

Comment: Are you sure your Python code works differently? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe `^` and `$` aren't necessary.

[sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) is suggesting this expression:

```
(?<=^|\r?\n)\bTEXT\b
```

which would work in `c#` or python.

I'm not so sure why it would work OK in Python, `^(TEXT ?)$` pattern basically shouldn't work in Python for this case, but apparently I'm not right.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zQK7yg/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?=^|\r?\n)\bTEXT\b";
        string substitution = @"MTEXT";
        string input = @"TEXT Some data before TEXT some data after

TEXTY Some data before  TEXT 

TEXT Some data before TEXT some data after

TEXT Some data before  TEXT NOTTEXT ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```